# Github reusable workflow access reference files

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have the following folder structure in my reusable workflow:

[image]

And this helm code is inside the `mvn-build` workflow:

```
helm package ./chart/ --version ${{ steps.projectVersion.outputs.PROJECT_VERSION }} --app-version ${{ steps.projectVersion.outputs.PROJECT_VERSION }}
```

And this helm command is failing because it cannot seem to find the `chart` folder. I have tried referencing it in several ways, but cannot seem to be able to make it reachable.

How can I reference a folder on a command inside a workflow? What if I wanted to reference a folder that is in the repository that called this workflow?

**UPDATE:**
I was able to make the reference work for the repo that is calling this workflow using the following:

```
 CHART_FOLDER: ${{ github.workspace }}/chart
```

However, as I said, this references the directory of the repo that called the workflow, not the workflow's directory.